# Best practice for define layout Component in react with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router in my app.So my route implement in react-router version 3. Today we know that react-router is release the new version. My question is how to migrate the layout of app into v4. for example my I'm define this three component `Layout`,`Home` and `Profile`.So I write this code for Router in version 4:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Layout}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
 </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

My problem is when change the route to `profile`, the layout component is not show. How the best practice to solve this problem? 
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `exact` prop from the Route rendering Layout component. See [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

More generally how to migrate try following [this guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md) and also I'd suggest just looking at [these examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) of react router 4.